# FileInputStream counts more newline char than there are

Tags: java, android, newline, fileinputstream

I am using OpenCSV to read and write csv files in an Android application and recently ran into a weird (to me) issue while parsing the following csv file that I created using Notepad++:

```
0.0,0.0,"HTML Snippet example","<html><p><a href=""http://google.com/"">URL Link</a></p></html>"
0.0,0.0,"HTML Snippet example","<html><p>Paragraph</p><p><blockquote>Blockquote</blockquote></p><br>Line break before and after<br><p>Cite tag: <cite>The Scream</cite> by Edward Munch. Painted in 1893.</p><p>Dfn tag: <dfn>HTML</dfn> is the standard markup language for creating web pages.</p><div align=""right"">Div align right</div><p>em tag: <em>Emphasized text</em></p><p><font size=""100px"" color=""red"">Font tag 100px color red</font></p><h1>H1 tag</h1><h2>H2 tag</h2><h3>H3 tag</h3><h4>H4 tag</h4><h5>H5 tag</h5><h6>H6 tag</h6><p><small>Small text</small></p><p><big>Big</big> Text</p><p><b>Bold</b> Text</p><p><i>Italic text</i></p><p><strike>Strike text</strike></p><p><strong>Strong text</strong></p><p>This text contains <sub>subscript</sub> text.</p><p>This text contains <sup>super</sup> text.</p></html>"
0.0,0.0,"HTML Snippet example","<html><p><tt>Teletype text</tt></p></html>"
0.0,0.0,"HTML Snippet example","<html><p><u>Underlined text</u></p></html>"
```

When I read the file I end up getting the four rows (0-3) plus row index 1 & 2 again so I end up with the following in memory:

```
0.0,0.0,"HTML Snippet example","<html><p><a href=""http://google.com/"">URL Link</a></p></html>"
0.0,0.0,"HTML Snippet example","<html><p>Paragraph</p><p><blockquote>Blockquote</blockquote></p><br>Line break before and after<br><p>Cite tag: <cite>The Scream</cite> by Edward Munch. Painted in 1893.</p><p>Dfn tag: <dfn>HTML</dfn> is the standard markup language for creating web pages.</p><div align=""right"">Div align right</div><p>em tag: <em>Emphasized text</em></p><p><font size=""100px"" color=""red"">Font tag 100px color red</font></p><h1>H1 tag</h1><h2>H2 tag</h2><h3>H3 tag</h3><h4>H4 tag</h4><h5>H5 tag</h5><h6>H6 tag</h6><p><small>Small text</small></p><p><big>Big</big> Text</p><p><b>Bold</b> Text</p><p><i>Italic text</i></p><p><strike>Strike text</strike></p><p><strong>Strong text</strong></p><p>This text contains <sub>subscript</sub> text.</p><p>This text contains <sup>super</sup> text.</p></html>"
0.0,0.0,"HTML Snippet example","<html><p><tt>Teletype text</tt></p></html>"
0.0,0.0,"HTML Snippet example","<html><p><u>Underlined text</u></p></html>"
0.0,0.0,"HTML Snippet example","<html><p>Paragraph</p><p><blockquote>Blockquote</blockquote></p><br>Line break before and after<br><p>Cite tag: <cite>The Scream</cite> by Edward Munch. Painted in 1893.</p><p>Dfn tag: <dfn>HTML</dfn> is the standard markup language for creating web pages.</p><div align=""right"">Div align right</div><p>em tag: <em>Emphasized text</em></p><p><font size=""100px"" color=""red"">Font tag 100px color red</font></p><h1>H1 tag</h1><h2>H2 tag</h2><h3>H3 tag</h3><h4>H4 tag</h4><h5>H5 tag</h5><h6>H6 tag</h6><p><small>Small text</small></p><p><big>Big</big> Text</p><p><b>Bold</b> Text</p><p><i>Italic text</i></p><p><strike>Strike text</strike></p><p><strong>Strong text</strong></p><p>This text contains <sub>subscript</sub> text.</p><p>This text contains <sup>super</sup> text.</p></html>"
0.0,0.0,"HTML Snippet example","<html><p><tt>Teletype text</tt></p></html>"
```

So I created a method to count the number of newlines trying to figure out why the BufferedReader in OpenCSV is returning duplicate lines and my method counts 7 newline characters, '\n', yet Notepad++ only counts 4. Here is my method that counts the number of newline characters:

```
int count = 0;
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(this._filePath);
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
int n;
while ((n = stream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (buffer[i] == '\n') 
            count++;
    }
}
return count;
```

I know it has something to do with the html tags since it only occurs with files that have multiple html tags in the same line but I have found no pattern that keys me in on which tag or combination of tags causes the issue.

Thanks in advance!

This issue has been resolve. I am not sure exactly what happened but I was emailing my test device the csv file and opening it from the gmail app with my app and I think that either A) there was something messed up in the file that I could not see or atleast not obvious from the tests I did or B) the gmail apps content provider has a bug and was screwing up the file. I opened the file with other text editing applications and it looked ok so I am not convinced that was the issue.

I started with a copy of that file to try arranging the html tags in different orders and this time I had the test device plugged into my PC via USB and was using Explorer to copy the files to the device and the issue seemed to magically disappear. So then I email the same file to the device again and opened it from the gmail app it worked perfectly. Since I cannot reproduce this issue I am going chalk it up to some odd in the text file that was causing the issue. Hopefully I never see this issue again considering I have spent about 6 hours trying to resolve it.